# ssl certificate verification failed

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, x509

I am having a server CA certificate, client certificate and client key files. Trying to create the PEM file in below format.

```
    # client certificate
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    XXXXXXXXXXXMVTXXXXXXXXXXXXBKueuqI6lfYygoKOhJJoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ...
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXhZSZg=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----

    # Private key
    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    XXXXXXXXXXXMVTXXXXXXXXXXXXBKueuqI6lfYygoKOhJJoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ...
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXhZSZg2Cg6zn
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

    # Server CA certificate
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    XXXXXXXXXXXMVTXXXXXXXXXXXXBKueuqI6lfYygoKOhJJoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ...
    XXXXXXXXXXXMVTXXXXXXXXXXXXBKueuqI6lfYygoKOhJJoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXhZSZgxxxxxxx4gv/5blW3Dc=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Before creating the PEM file, when I try validating the cert and key using openssl I get below error.

```
  openssl x509 -in clientCert.crt  -text
    unable to load certificate
    4559283820:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.260.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:683:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

```
  openssl pkey -in keyfile.key -pubout -outform pem
    unable to load key
    4684559980:error:09FFF064:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad base64 decode:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.260.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:800:
```

the key and certificates are from a trusted party. So any Idea what I do wrong here?

Comment: Both the commands look good. I suspect issue with the files. Are you able to `cat` the file and see the proper `certificate` and `private key` respectively?

Comment: @AlokSingh, sorry for not responding in the thread and thanks! I stopped the project long before, so not checked this thread, but you are right. These files were generated by the Google Kubernetes service (GKE) and it can only be interpreted by kubectl with proper gcloud authentication it seems.